# Sending an array of records from mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to show the title and content for all the posts stored in a mongodb collection to the main page. How should I pass all the records to the view, so that I can loop through the data easily in the view.

Currently I'm just sending one record (in the form of separate variable), but I want to send the array of records, which I can easily loop through to display data in the EJS view.

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Story = mongoose.model( 'Story' );
exports.home=function(req,res){
      var title,content;
      console.log("Fetching Stories");
      Story.findOne({}, function(err,story){
           res.render('home',{title:story.title,content:story.content});

         });
  }
```

I understand I have to use **Story.find()** but how to add all the records

Answer (score 0):

> Use `.find({},cb)` instead of `.findOne()`

`find()` returns all matching documents in an array.

```
Story.find({}, function(err, stories) {
  res.render('home', {stories:stories});
});
```

`stories` will be array of all the objects

Comment: But when I try to access the elements of the array Its not showing up `   <% if( typeof(stories) !== 'undefined' ) {%>

                           <% for(var i=0; i < stories.length; i++) { %>
                               <h1><%= stories[i].title %></h1><br/>
                               <p><%= stories[i].content %></p>
                           <% } %>
                        <%}%>`

Comment: Got it I was not sending that array to view  Story.find({}, function(err,stories){
               console.log("All Stories : "+stories);
                res.render('home',{stories:stories});

              });

Comment: On a side question, I am only showing the summary of 5 blogs on home page, I want to give a link along with story summary. On clicking that link, that complete story will be shown. Although I can do that with _id field like **makethemarks.org/story/568dff3ec8250e90d1084746** , is there any other way to do that _id field looks ugly in URL.

Comment: There is a concept called as `URl slug`. You can create a slug for each story by using name of the story. Make sure it is unique.. If there is any other unique key in your document then you can use that too.

Comment: How about title of the story e.g. **Colin Ibraham Story** and the slug will be colin-ibraham-story, but what if the title is **Colin Ibraham's Story** then to make it colin-ibrahams-story. I will have to parse the title to generate the slug, any thoughts on that

Comment: Of Course you will have to parse it..There will _n_ possibilities for this. You may find snippets which will do this for you. Also note if __Colin Ibraham Story__ exists in the DB then ? Slug has to be _colin-ibraham-story-1_ I would do this server-side..

Comment: Do you find anything wrong in that ? I have been following this since a long time..

Comment: Thank you very much @Rayon I will implement this

Comment: I already accepted it , I have less reputation , after some time it will become public. Previously I was using SO with different account. Thanks again